# 'Cannot get iis pickup directory' in Windows Server 2012

Tags: smtp, iis-6, asp.net, windows-server-2012, iis-8

Our system moved from Windows Server 2003(Enterprise SP2) & IIS 6.
And new system is Windows Server 2012(Standard) and IIS 6(for smtp mail) & 8.
I copied all of web application files and IIS settings, another function is ok but..
email system is something wrong. 
for example, 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

exception: system.Net.Mail.SmtpException: cannot get iis pickup directory.

line 284:                    SendMail sendmail = new SendMail();
**line 285:                    sendmail.GetSendMail(messagefrom, Useremail, mailsubject, message);**

stack trace:
[SmtpException: cannot get iis pickup directory.]
   System.Net.Mail.IisPickupDirectory.GetPickupDirectory() +1894
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1956518
   CommonDll.SendMail.GetSendMail(String messagefrom, String Useremail, String mailsubject, String message) +466
   ASP.common_users_courserecordadd_aspx.AddBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\"sourcefile.aspx":285
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981

Microsoft .NET Framework v:2.0.50727.6407; ASP.NET v:2.0.50727.6387 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

in Develop server(2008 R2 Ent SP1, IIS6 & 7.5), it works well. 
confused.

Comment: Even though it might be obvious what you're asking, it's preferred if you actually do ask a question, instead of just presenting an error.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll re-write this question soon.

Answer (score -1):

This should help: [Setting up SMTP under IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14161374/32429)